# Image not fitting inside of a DIV

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to place an image inside of a div. My problem is it is not fitting the image into the div, the image is in the div, it is just not **fit** to the div. It shows like a portion of the image because the image is bigger than the div. Can anyone help me get it to fit the whole image in the div without it being dis-proportional? I have the following:

**Markup**

```
 <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 newClass">
        <div class="module img-responsive" style="background-image: url(Images/my_image.jpg);">
            <header>
                <h1 style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">Text
                </h1>
                <h2 style="font-size: 13px; text-align: center;">Some more text
                </h2>
            </header>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
 /* Overlay text */
    .module {
        /*background-color: #abc;*/
        background-attachment: fixed;
        /*width: 400px;*/
        height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .module > header {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px 10px;
            background: inherit;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .module > header::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: -20px;
                left: 0;
                width: 200%;
                height: 200%;
                background: inherit;
                background-attachment: fixed;
                -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
                filter: blur(4px);
            }

            .module > header::after {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            }

            .module > header > h1 {
                margin: 0;
                color: white;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .module > header > h2 {
                margin: 0;
                color: white;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }
```

**Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is already answered, but you may prefer this solution better:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wym7zvrq/1/)

It allows scaling the image but without stretching it, as that is usually undesired.

If the image gets too big, you can always add a `max-width` to prevent that if you want.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 newClass">
    <div class="module img-responsive" style="background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuEZ2.jpg');">
        <header>
            <h1 style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">Text
            </h1>
            <h2 style="font-size: 13px; text-align: center;">Some more text
            </h2>
        </header>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuEZ2.jpg" style="visibility:hidden; width:100%; display:inherit"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 /* Overlay text */
    .module {
        background-size:cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

        .module > header {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background: inherit;
            background-position: bottom; 
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .module > header::before {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: inherit;
                background-size: cover;
                -webkit-filter: blur(4px);
                filter: blur(4px);
            }

            .module > header::after {
                content: "";
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
            }

            .module > header > h1 {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px 10px;
                color: white;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .module > header > h2 {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 10px 10px;
                color: white;
                position: relative;
                z-index: 1;
            }
```

Comment: You've placed the image in the div twice: once as a background, and also physically located in the div. This is a bit of a hack.  What if he wants to put additional content in the div, above the header?  It also forces the div to take the shape of the image, meaning all images must be sized the same before using this in multiple sections.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of a hack to get the height of the image. If OP wants more content in the div above the header, I would add a wrapping div around it all and have the current header rules apply to that div instead. Some CSS would have to be changed ofc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `background-attachment: fixed` and implement `background-size` as follows.  Here's the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/xoLad17k/).

```
.module{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /* other css */
}
```

Comment: Make sure you remove `background-attachment: fixed;` as well.  I added a demo.

Comment: Note: This is more flexible than the accepted answer, which physically places the image inside the div and blocks all other content.  This also gives you an exact stretch.

Answer (score 0):

you have another class called newClass that you haven't supplied mark-up for _ 
i'm just wondering if it has relevant parameters that might affect the outcome of .module class?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 newClass">
        <div class="module img-responsive" style="background-image: url(Images/my_image.jpg);background-size:cover;">
            <header>
                <h1 style="font-size: 20px; text-align: center;">Text
                </h1>
                <h2 style="font-size: 13px; text-align: center;">Some more text
                </h2>
            </header>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set background-size to cover ie...

```
.img-responsive{
    background-size: cover
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a background image here. Try setting background-size to "contain" or "cover" on your module class. Be aware that background size is not supported in older versions of Internet Explorer.